# Jackson JSON difference between JsonNode and ObjectNode

Tags: jackson

I am using Jackson for JSON parsing.
What is the difference between `JsonNode` and `ObjectNode`?

And which to use for mapping JSON in string format.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### Quick answer

- [`JsonNode`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html): Abstract class, used when **reading** a JSON document.
- [`ObjectNode`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html): Concrete implementation, used when **building or modifying** a JSON document.

Keep reading for a more detailed answer.

### `JsonNode`

[`JsonNode`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) is an *abstract* class used as the base class for all JSON nodes, which form the basis of JSON Tree Model that Jackson implements.

Quoting the [`JsonNode`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) documentation:

> As a general design rule, most accessors (*getters*) methods are included in this base class, to allow for traversing structure without type casts.
>
> Mutators methods (*setters*), however, need to be accessed through specific sub-classes (such as [`ObjectNode`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html) and [`ArrayNode`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ArrayNode.html)).
>
> This seems sensible because proper type information is generally available when building or modifying trees, but less often when reading a tree (newly built from parsed JSON content).

The [`JsonNode`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) concrete implementations can be found in the [`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/package-summary.html) package.

### `ObjectNode`

[`ObjectNode`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html) is a *concrete* implementation of [`JsonNode`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) that maps a JSON object, and a JSON object is [defined as following](http://www.json.org/):

> An *object* is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins with `{` (*left brace*) and ends with `}` (*right brace*). Each name is followed by `:` (*colon*) and the name/value pairs are separated by `,` (*comma*).
>
> [image: JSON object]