# Springframework unable to read http post

Tags: java, json, spring, angular

My front end is posting a `json` object:

```
[{"FUND_CODE":"testFUND","PORTF_CODE":"testcode","CLIENT_STAT":null,"CLIENT_LOCAL_CURR":null,"CLIENT_START_DT":"2017-04-06","CLIENT_END_DT":"9998-12-31","CREATED_USER_ID":"testuser","CREATED_DATETIME":"2017-05-04","LAST_UPDATE_USER":null,"LAST_UPDATE_DT":null}]
```

The controller is posting above `json` using:

```
deleteTableData = (schema: string, tableName: string, records: string[]): Observable<number> => {
    if (records.length > 0){
      const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      });
      try {
        return this._http.post<number>(this.moduleUrl + '/delete?schemaName=' + schema + "&tableName=" + tableName, records, { headers: headers });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } 
    }
  }
```

My backend is receiving like this:

```
@CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<RestWrapper> delete(@RequestParam String schemaName, @RequestParam String tableName, @RequestBody Json body){
        StringBuilder resStr = new StringBuilder();
        log.info("POST REQUEST RECEIVED ==> " + schemaName + " && " + tableName + " && " + body.value());

        return new ResponseEntity<>(new RestWrapper(resStr.toString()), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

**ERROR** that I am getting:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.Json out of START_ARRAY token
```

How can I resolve this error?

**EDIT**

Forgot to mention an important requirement: I cannot create specific data model at server. There are multiple tables to update and the list of tables will grow gradually. Hence, I need a generic API to perform actions.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are reading the object with wrong class. In the `RequestBody`, the json that is coming in is not compatible with `springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.Json`.

If you are trying to use some specific class by name `Json`, please check if you have imported correct package.

Alternatively, you can create simple DTO for the json body.

```
class JsonRequest {
    @JsonProperty("FUND_CODE")
    private String fundCode;

    @JsonProperty("CLIENT_STAT")
    private String clientStat;
    .
    .
    .

    @JsonProperty("LAST_UPDATE_DT")
    private String lastUpdateDt;
    .
    .
    // getters and setters if needed 
}
```

and then change to

```
 public ResponseEntity<RestWrapper> delete(..., @RequestBody JsonRequest jsonRequest){
```

Comment: Agree with your point about the package imported for Json. I tried with 'org.json.JSONObject' & 'org.json.JSONArray' but both gave me empty HTTP body. The good news is that the error was gone. What type should be used here?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, you should create your own type `JsonRequest` so that you can map each attribute to java field. `JSONArray` or  `JSONObject` won't work because their json representation is different that what you are sending.

Comment: OK got it. The requirement here is that I cannot create specific data models, because the front end Json could be of different attributes for multiple tables. I need a generic API to perform this action. I think I would have to go for plain string typed HTTP body then tokenize...

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved when I changed HTTP body data type from `Json` to `JsonNode`

[Jackson JSON difference between JsonNode and ObjectNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38759976/jackson-json-difference-between-jsonnode-and-objectnode?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Correct me if I'm wrong, My understand is that since I do not have definite model defined for incoming JSON, I will have to use JsonNode which is an abstract class.

If anyone knows more about it, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
public ResponseEntity<RestWrapper> delete(..., @RequestBody JsonRequest[] jsonRequest)
```

and then make the pojo class with proper json property like

```
       @JsonProperty("CREATED_DATETIME")
       private String CREATED_DATETIME;
```

you will get the proper array of object and i use it already.